# How can I navigate to the next or previous procedure?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb6

In VB6 you can easily go to next procedure by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> and also previous procedure by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

However I can't find any way to do that using Visual Studio 2010 programming VB.NET; I want to scroll down or up to go to the previous or next procedure using a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It is in the Edit menu, at the bottom, "Next Method" and "Previous Method".  If it doesn't show the shortcut keystroke for these commands then use Tools + Customize, Keyboard to assign them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, keybindings *do* exist and you're in luck; the keybindings below relate to Visual Studio 2010's Visual Basic.

*It's come to my attention that these default keybindings aren't available in some installations of Visual Studio. If this is the case for you then proceed with the key-binding instructions below this section.*

**[Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx)**

- **Next Method or Type**: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>↓</kbd>  or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>
- **Previous Method or Type**: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>↑</kbd>  or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd>

All keybindings for Visual Studio 2010's Visual Basic can be found [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/6/296AAFA4-669A-46FE-9509-93753F7B0F46/VS-KB-Brochure-VB-Letter.pdf), and more keybindings for other programming languages in Visual Studio can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189)

Same keybindings for other versions:

[**Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and 2015 (and any other version without the default keybindings)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.120).aspx)

Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015 [Does not appear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.120).aspx) to have any `Edit.NextMethod` or `Edit.PreviousMethod` keybindings and the same behaviour can be observed for some installations of other Visual Studio versions, instead you'll have to assign your own:

- `TOOLS` >> `OPTIONS` >> `ENVIRONMENT` >> `KEYBOARD` >> Select `Visual Basic 6` from the `Apply the following keyboard mapping scheme` dropdown:

[image]

- Find `Edit.NextMethod` and `Edit.PreviousMethod` in the Commands box:

[image]

- Click within the `Press Shortcut Keys` box and press the shortcut keys you want to assign on the keyboard. In this case, let's copy the shortcut keys from Visual Studio 2010:

[image]

- Once you've done that, click `Assign` and then do the same for the other command; the shortcut keys will now work

The *Default* key-binding is slightly misleading; it only applies if you open a file with Visual Studio that is not supported by the IDE, therefore you should be careful that you do not add a keybinding under this.