# Finding keyboard shortcuts by shortcut, rather than by command name, in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Somehow, something has mapped a composite keyboard shortcut to `Ctrl+S, ??`, where `??` signifies a second, unknown, keystroke. This is pretty unpractical, since that means that `Ctrl+S` no longer saves the document.

Is there a way to locate the binding(s) that start with `Ctrl+S` without having to look at them all manually?

Comment: By examining shortcuts by recently installed or updated extensions I was able to find the culprit this time, but I'd still like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in `TOOLS` >> `OPTIONS` >> `ENVIRONMENT` >> `KEYBOARD`.

- Navigate to `TOOLS` >> `OPTIONS` >> `ENVIRONMENT` >> `KEYBOARD`:

[image]

- Click in the `Press shortcut keys` textbox and press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> key combination on your keyboard.
- Click on the `Shortcut currently used by` dropdown to reveal all commands that use the shortcut:

[image]

---

Note that this was with Visual Studio 2015, and [older versions might not have the same feature available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905623/how-can-i-navigate-to-the-next-or-previous-procedure/27906992#27906992).

Comment: Fabulous! Thanks a lot for taking the time to provide screenshots and all :)

Comment: (I'm not allowed to accept an answer in another couple of minutes, but I will when I may!)

Comment: @TomasLycken No problem; when I saw your question I thought of another answer I wrote (the one I linked) and realised that the functionality was there.